# Specify a column type across multiple columns with tidy-selection in readr package

Tags: r, file-io, readr, across, tidyselect

I attempt to use `read_csv` from `{readr}` to read a `CSV` file into R. To demonstrate my real issue, I reset the argument `guess_max` to 5 at first (default is 1000)

```r
library(readr)
formals(read_csv)$guess_max <- 5
```

and take a smaller literal data for example:

```r
csv <- I(
"ID, Col1, Col2, VarA, VarB, VarC
1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA
2, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA
3, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA
4, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA
5, 0, 1, x, y, z
6, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA")

read_csv(csv)

# # A tibble: 6 × 6
#      ID  Col1    Col2    VarA   VarB   VarC 
#   <dbl>  <lgl>   <lgl>   <lgl>  <lgl>  <lgl>
# 1     1  NA      NA      NA     NA     NA   
# 2     2  NA      NA      NA     NA     NA   
# 3     3  NA      NA      NA     NA     NA   
# 4     4  NA      NA      NA     NA     NA   
# 5     5  FALSE*  TRUE*   NA*    NA*    NA*
# 6     6  NA      NA      NA     NA     NA
```

`*`: parsing issues occur

---

Affected by `guess_max`, only the first 5 lines (column names and `ID` 1 to 4) are used for guessing column types. Because the values in `ID` 1 to 4 are all missing, all columns are guessed as `logical` and are parsed incorrectly:

- `0`, `1` (integer) → `FALSE`, `TRUE` (logical)
- `'x'`, `'y'`, `'z'` (character) → `NA` (logical)

In this case I have to set `col_types` manually:

```r
read_csv(csv, col_types = cols(Col1 = col_integer(), Col2 = col_integer(),
                               VarA = col_character(), VarB = col_character(), VarC = col_character()))

# # A tibble: 6 × 6                                                                                                   
#      ID  Col1  Col2 VarA  VarB  VarC 
#   <dbl> <int> <int> <chr> <chr> <chr>
# 1     1    NA    NA NA    NA    NA   
# 2     2    NA    NA NA    NA    NA   
# 3     3    NA    NA NA    NA    NA   
# 4     4    NA    NA NA    NA    NA   
# 5     5     0     1 x     y     z    
# 6     6    NA    NA NA    NA    NA
```

Supplying the column types one by one is annoying when there are much more columns. If the names of those columns I want to specify have some patterns, I expect to use the *<tidy-select>*-like syntax to specify a type across multiple columns, such as `across()` in `{dplyr}`. The pseudocode is like:

```r
read_csv(csv, col_types = cols(across(starts_with("Col"), col_integer()),
                               across(starts_with("Var"), col_character())))
```

Is it possible by `readr` itself or other add-on packages?

Thanks in advance!

---

##### Edits

I need to use `col_xxx()` rather than their abbreviations (`'i'`, `'c'`, etc.) to create column specification for more general purpose, e.g.

```r
cols(across(contains("Date"), col_date(format = "%m-%d-%Y")),
     across(Fct1:Fct9, col_factor(levels = custom_levels)))
```

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73642144/is-it-possible-to-use-tidyselect-helpers-with-the-cols-only-function) might be helpful

Comment: @OP Could you point out why the linked answer fails to meet your needs? It seems to do exactly what you are asking for. Stating your expectations clearly will substantially improve your chance of getting a good answer

Comment: @peter861222 the link you found is helpful but It does not use tidy-selection, and it use if...else... to specify column types, so I need to adjust many places whenever I read a different new file. I want a more systematic and functional approach.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `read_delim()` family has used tidy-selection for selecting columns with the argument `col_select`. You can take advantage of this argument to incorporate tidy-selection into the specification of column types. The following is a simple implementation. The key is setting `n_max = 0L` to only read the line of column names.

##### Version 1

```r
col_across <- function(.cols, .fns, file) {
  col_selected <- read_csv(file, n_max = 0L, col_select = {{.cols}}, show_col_types = FALSE)
  lapply(col_selected, function(x) .fns)
}
```

###### Usage

```r
df <- read_csv(csv,
  col_types = c(col_across(starts_with("Col"), col_integer(), csv),
                col_across(VarA:VarC, col_factor(c('x', 'y', 'z')), csv))
)
```

The way above is simple but just passable with some **drawbacks**:

1. The same file source (i.e. object `csv`) needs to be passed to every `col_across()`.
2. The `read_delim` family includes several variants, e.g. `read_csv`, `read_csv2`, `read_tsv`. When calling `df <- read_xxx(...)`, you have to confirm that `col_across()` has used the consistent `read_xxx` to read column names.

---

---

##### Version 2

An improved version of `col_across` is developed that automatically detects which `read_xxx` is used, and retrieves the file source from the outer call.

```r
col_across <- function(.cols, .fns) {
  sc <- sys.call(1L)
  sc <- match.call(match.fun(sc[[1L]]), sc)
  read_call <- sc[c(1L, match("file", names(sc), 0L))]
  read_call$n_max <- 0L
  read_call$col_select <- substitute(.cols)
  read_call$show_col_types <- FALSE
  lapply(eval(read_call, parent.frame()), function(x) .fns)
}
```

###### Usage

```r
df <- read_csv(csv,
  col_types = c(col_across(starts_with("Col"), col_integer()),
                col_across(VarA:VarC, col_factor(c('x', 'y', 'z'))))
)
```

> Note that this version of `col_across` must only be used inside the `read_delim` family, as `across` is to `mutate` in `{dplyr}`.

###### Examine the column specifications

```r
spec(df)

# cols(
#   ID = col_double(),
#   Col1 = col_integer(),
#   Col2 = col_integer(),
#   VarA = col_factor(levels = c("x", "y", "z"), ordered = FALSE, include_na = FALSE),
#   VarB = col_factor(levels = c("x", "y", "z"), ordered = FALSE, include_na = FALSE),
#   VarC = col_factor(levels = c("x", "y", "z"), ordered = FALSE, include_na = FALSE)
# )
```